# SQL works on Oracle SQL Developer but won't works on C# code

Tags: c#, sql, oracle

I have this SQL that works if i just execute on Oracle SQL Developer:

```
SELECT * FROM MYTABLE 
WHERE LOWER(TRANSLATE(DESCRIPTION, 'âáàãêéèîíìôóòõûúùç', 'aaaaeeeiiioooouuuc')) 
LIKE LOWER(TRANSLATE('%são paulo%', 'âáàãêéèîíìôóòõûúùç', 'aaaaeeeiiioooouuuc'))
```

But when is execute on C# code, wont work. The result always is 0.

```
string translate = "'âáàãêéèîíìôóòõûúùç', 'aaaaeeeiiioooouuuc'";
string query = string.Format("SELECT * FROM {0} 
                             WHERE LOWER(TRANSLATE(DESCSITE, {2})) 
                             LIKE LOWER(TRANSLATE({1}, {2}))", 
                             TABLE, string.Format("'%{0}%'", str.ToLower()), translate);
```

UPDATE

This is how show in the breakpoint:

```
SELECT * FROM PROD 
WHERE TRANSLATE(LOWER(DESCSITE), 'âáàãêéèîíìôóòõûúùç', 'aaaaeeeiiioooouuuc') 
LIKE TRANSLATE(LOWER('%macarrão%'), 'âáàãêéèîíìôóòõûúùç', 'aaaaeeeiiioooouuuc')
```

And the same problem. Works on Oracle SQL Developer bu wont on C# code.

UPDATE

I tried this, but but in this case is not working to.

```
string query = string.Format("SELECT * FROM {0} 
                 WHERE LOWER(TRANSLATE(DESCSITE, {1})) 
                 LIKE LOWER(TRANSLATE(:DESCSITE, {1}))", TABLE, translate);
List<OracleParameter> parameters = new List<OracleParameter>();
parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":DESCSITE", string.Format("'%{0}%'", str)));
```

If I only try this, i know tha will work, but I have to check the others  things.

```
string query = string.Format(@"SELECT * FROM {0} WHERE CODIPROD = :CODIPROD", TABLE);
List<OracleParameter> parameters = new List<OracleParameter>();
parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":CODIPROD", id));
```

UPDATE

I'm using for retun:

**OracleCommand command;
command.ExecuteReader();**

UPDATE

I tried put **Unicode=True** on the ConnectionString but nothing

UPDATE

This is how I execute the query. Everything works fine with characters without accents:

```
OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection();
connection.Open();

OracleTransaction transaction;
transaction = connection.BeginTransaction();

OracleCommand command;
command = connection.CreateCommand();
command.Transaction = transaction;
command.CommandText = commandText;

OracleParameter parameter;
command.Parameters.Add(parameter);

reader = command.ExecuteReader();

while (reader.Read())
{
    // Get data
}
```

So, the last try (yesterday 5 pm) I made this:

```
String x = "SELECT * FROM PROD WHERE TRANSLATE(LOWER(DESCSITE), 'âáàãêéèîíìôóòõûúùç', 'aaaaeeeiiioooouuuc') LIKE LOWER(TRANSLATE('%"+str+"%', 'âáàãêéèîíìôóòõûúùç', 'aaaaeeeiiioooouuuc'))";
```

And works fine. But this way I know that is not right.

Comment: What does query look like if you put a breakpoint on it? Is it as expected compared to working SQL? and what happens if you run that same SQL directly.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to use `TRANSLATE(LOWER(...)))` instead of `LOWER(TRANSLATE(...))`? Or doesn't your data contain uppercase letters with accents?

Comment: @DaveZych: Isn't the argument `translate` used to replace the `{2}` placeholders?

Comment: This is going to be a slow performer (thankfully, Oracle should be smart enough to do this in one table-scan, not two, but it's going to be running through `DESCRIPTION` 3 times... probably).  Does your version of oracle allow you to save a 'derive' (or calculated) column?  That'd at least mean you weren't always doing `LOWER()` and `TRANSLATE()`, although it wouldn't save you from wildcarded searches.

Comment: @Codo you're right, I didn't scroll far enough or something. Ha!

Comment: your column in sql query from sql developer(`DESCRIPTION`) and C# code is diff(`DESCSITE`).

Comment: Sorry, I wrote (DESCRIPTION) but was here on stackoverflow.

Comment: how are you returning rows, are you using ExecuteScalar or ExecuteNonQuery or something else? Are you returning refcursor?

Comment: Once again (see my answer): The TRANSLATE function is case-sensitive. Call `TRANSLATE(LOWER(..),..)` not `LOWER(TRANSLATE(...))`.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes Here:

SELECT * FROM {0} WHERE **TRANSLATE(UPPER(DESCSITE)**, {2}) LIKE **UPPER(TRANSLATE({1}, {2}))**

But not working...

Comment: Your translation strings `"âáàãêéèîíìôóòõûúùç"` and `"aaaaeeeiiioooouuuc"` are lower-case. They will only translate lower case letters. Therfore you must make the string to be translated lower-case!

Comment: You are adding the parameters to a user-defined list. You must add them to to command: `command.Parameters.Add(...)`.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes, whait...
I'll check.

Comment: Please see my update which shows how to perfom a query with C#.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the functions in the wrong order. The TRANSLATE function is case-sensitive. Therefore you must make the strings lower case **before** translating.

```
SELECT * FROM {0}
WHERE TRANSLATE(LOWER(DESCSITE), {2}) LIKE TRANSLATE({1}, {2})
```

Also, the second `LOWER` is superfluous, since you do with `str.ToLower()` already.

---

**UPDATE**

It is still not clear how you really execute the query. Here is an example of how it can be done

```
string connectionString = "...";
string query = "...";
using (var connection = new OracleConnection(connectionString)) {
    var command = new OracleCommand(query);
    command.Parameters.Add(":DESCSITE", OracleType.NVarChar);
    connection.Open();
    using (OracleDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader()) {
        int descSiteOrdinal = reader.GetOrdinal("DESCSITE");
        while (reader.Read()) {
            Console.WriteLine(reader.GetString(descSiteOrdinal));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: SELECT * FROM {0} WHERE TRANSLATE(LOWER(DESCSITE), {2}) LIKE TRANSLATE({1}, {2})

The same =/
Not working

Comment: @user1958882 - Please update your question with the new information.

Answer (score -1):

I've resolved it adding this in my connectionString like this (Unicode=true;):

```
    protected string conexionOraclePruebas = @"Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=xxx)(HOST=xxx)(PORT=xxx)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=xxx)(SERVICE_NAME=xxx)));"
+ " User Id=xxx;Password=xxx;Min Pool Size=x;Connection Lifetime=x; "
+ " Unicode=true;";
```

My query was:

```
query += " AND translate(UPPER(" + field + "), 'ÁÉÍÓÚÀÈÌÒÙÃÊÎÕÛÂÄËÏÖÔÜÇÑ', 'AEIOUAEIOUAEIOUAAEIOOUCN') "
+"LIKE translate(UPPER('%" + this.value.ToString() + "%'), 'ÁÉÍÓÚÀÈÌÒÙÃÊÎÕÛÂÄËÏÖÔÜÇÑ', 'AEIOUAEIOUAEIOUAAEIOOUCN')";
```

Comment: I tried cleaning up this answer a bit, but it could probably be improved with some line breaks and/or indents in the code blocks. I'm not familiar enough with SQL to say where exactly they should go.